# ZendFramework fetching data from database going wrong

Tags: zend-framework

Hey I have 3 instances for an admin user to display comments, users and clubs. At the moment im working on just getting them displayed the user and clubs work fine but the comments doesn't which is strange as for all of them i used the same code but replaced the variables respectively.

Comments Model:

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Comments extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'comments';

    public function getComments($id) {
        $id = (int) $id;
        $row = $this->fetchRow('id = ' . $id);
        if (!$row) {
            throw new Exception("Count not find row $id");
        }
        return $row->toArray();
    }

}
```

AdminViewCommentsController:

```
<?php

class AdminViewCommentsController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->assign('title', 'Admin - View Comments');
        $this->view->headTitle($this->view->title, 'PREPEND');
        $comments = new Application_Model_DbTable_Comments();
        $this->view->comments = $comments->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

And finally the view:

```
<table>
<th>Comment</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th></th>
<?php foreach($this->comments as $comments) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($comments->comment);?></td>
    <td><?php echo $this->escape($comments->date);?></td>
    <td><a href="#">Delete!</a></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I have tried re-typing these multiple times, but something somewhere is going wrong and I am lost as to what it would be.

Thanks

Comment: In your `indexAction()` method do a `var_dump($this->view->comments)` after you localize, and see if you have values, it might be an escaping problem.

Comment: Like this -> http://pastebin.com/5XFqS0ji it doesn't change anything..

Comment: It's not supposed to change anything, it's only to confirm that you indeed have comment data.

Comment: of course, sorry a bit tried. Yeah I did that and I have comments. It is something in the view thats breaking the application. Removing the td lines solves the breakage, but obviously no data. So sounds like it is an escaping problem.

Comment: problem is I dont know what this means.. or how to fix it..

Comment: can you put an example of your returned comments ?

Comment: Wonder if one of the comments has data which cannot be escaped properly? When you var_dump it in the controller, do you notice anything out of the ordinary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys the field name in the database was wrong! It should have been 'comment_date', not just 'date'

Sorry